# Tkinter Entry widget on macOS Monterey is barely visible

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

When using the themed Tkinter Entry widget on macOS Monterey, the text field is barely visible in the window as shown in the example below. The text field area for the Entry widget is the same color as the window background and it has a thin border. The native text field in a Mac app has a white background and thick border. I thought the themed Tkinter widgets use a similar style as the operating system but this doesn't appear to be the case for macOS. Is there something else I must do to make the Entry widget text field more visible and native looking on macOS?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyApp:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.configure_window()
        self.create_widgets()

    def configure_window(self):
        self.root.title('Example App')
        self.root.geometry('400x300')
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    def create_widgets(self):
        ttk.Label(text='Below is Entry widget').pack(pady=10)
        ttk.Entry().pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: window]

Comment: You can customize `ttk` themes and styles. Here's some [documention](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/ttk-themes.html) on the topic.

Comment: @martineau I'm aware of customization options for `ttk` widgets. But I thought the themed widgets adopted the style used by the operating system?